# How can i wait statement execution till UIAlertview button clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

HI am working on chat application , am sending file to friend like Skype, when i got file transfaring Request that method should return BOOL value . so after showing the alertview am waiting for user response

my code is  , alertview showing but UI is Blocked

```
-(BOOL)incommingFileRequest:(XMPPIQ *)inIq
{
    NSXMLElement *si = [inIq elementForName:@"si"];
    NSXMLElement *file = [si elementForName:@"file"];

    NSDictionary *dic = [file attributesAsDictionary];
    fileId = [inIq attributeStringValueForName:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"---filename--- %@",[file attributeForName:@"name"]);

    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n %@ ",[dic objectForKey:@"name"],[ self transformedValue:[dic objectForKey:@"size"]]];
    UIAlertView *alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incommming File" 
                                        message:name 
                                        delegate:self 
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Reject" 
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Accept", nil];

    alrt.tag = 1111; 
    [alrt show];

    while (buttonClicked == -1) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.25]];
    } 

    if (buttonClicked == 1) {
        NSLog(@"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~YES");
        return YES;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~NO");
        return NO;
    }
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if(alertview.tag == 1111){
       if (buttonIndex == 0){
            buttonClicked = buttonIndex;
       } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read any of the Apple Documentation around `UIAlertView` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html) or `UIAlertViewDelegate`?

Comment: This could as it is would never work in any application. What is `buttonClicked`? Where is this declared? If you have more code then you need to share what you have we aren't mind readers

Comment: well done for all the downvotes on my questions/answers. How pathetic, flagged you to moderators.

Answer (score 2):

Make your ViewController implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol and implement the method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Do whatever you need to do after the alertView closes, depending on button indices

   if(alertview.tag == 1111){

       if (buttonIndex == 0){
        // First Button pressed
       } elif (buttonIndex == 1) {
        // Response if second button pressed
       }

  }
    // etc etc
}
```

Comment: this is simple UIAlertview Controller. Do u undrestued my Question .

Comment: @NagRaj Do you understand your question? `clickedButtonAtIndex:` is the method to do what you want in. If you want something else your question is very unclear what you want.

Comment: @Popeye with out understanding how can i ask the question.

Comment: @NagRaj Then you need to go back to basics and learn about what you are asking. Based on your question this actually answers it. You need to be more clear in what you want.

Comment: first listen one method shows the uialertview then retrun the value which you are selected on uialertview buttons.

Comment: @NagRaj What are you even talking about. What methods are you using? You have failed to give us a lot of information by the sounds of it. I'm voting to close based on this being unclear what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63751/discussion-between-nag-raj-and-popeye).

Comment: @NagRaj well done for all the downvotes on my questions/answers. How pathetic, flagged you to moderators

Comment: @Popeye Now read the question

Comment: @NagRaj No why should I help someone who has just gone and downvoted my questions/answers when all I was trying to do was get them to provide more information so I could help them?

Comment: if you do not understand my question then ask me other wise leave it, without understand my question how can u give down vote.

Comment: @NagRaj I did ask you and you downvoted my questions/answers and I do have an answer for you now but you have shot yourself in the foot if you think I will help you now. If you want peoples help on here you need to learn how this site works before asking a question. The reason for my downvote was perfectly valid, I asked for additional information and you didn't provide it that is the reason for the downvote system for poorly asked questions and poorly answered ones not to get revenge because someone else downvoted yours like you have done.

Comment: @NagRaj And just so you know your code doesn't make one little bit of sense

Comment: @Popeye Delete Your Answer..

Comment: @NagRaj I haven't put an answer but I have flagged you to moderators for abusing the downvoting system. And just so you know this answer is half way to be correct. My advise to you is go back a learn the basics because you clearly don't understand what the hell is going on and the purpose of `clickedButtonAtIndex:` and learn some manners as well, notice how everyone is downvoting and voting to close?

Comment: @Popeye u could not understand my question, then close your's ....

Comment: @NagRaj What???? You actually don't make any sense "then close your's" what is that even meant to mean? Your question made no sense what so ever and everyone seems to agree. How are we meant to help you if you aren't willing to help yourself. Stop blaming everyone else because you can't make your questions clear enough for us to help you, the only person missing out is yourself. If you don't like how this site works then you don't have to use it and if someone asks for additional information don't be rude just provide it especially if your the one wanting help.